# How to suppress a NotifyPropertyChanged event on a focused Input Control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

My application features a periodic database synchronisation. Whenever a synchronisation occurs, the values of all input controls are reset to the current values from the database.

However, when a synchronisation event occurs while typing a long text in a `TextBox` this is more than inconvenient.

The desired behaviour is that the value of an input control is not set to the value of the bound property in case that control currently has focus. As soon as the keyboard focus is lost, the current value should be synchronized back to the bound property and thereby to the database (which would be the default behaviour).

My first idea was to modify my controls so that the binding mode is automatically set to `OneWayToSource` while the input has keyboard focus.
Currently I do not see another option but to derive all sorts of input controls I have in my application which would be a lot of work.

Do you see a way to implement this kind of behaviour in a central location, so that it is used by all UI controls, preferably without subclassing `TextBox`, `ComboBox` etc.?

Comment: It isn't clear, what desired behavior is. Do you want to skip focused control or you want to skip update of bound property, if it's value was changed? What should happen on the next synchronization phase with values, which were skiped?

Comment: I added a paragraph to specify the desired behaviour =)

Comment: That's an interesting problem.  What do you do when the user is editing and you need to update the field?  Does the user win always?  It sounds like you'd need a custom Binding implementation that listens for user input and blocks updates from source...

Comment: Yes, the user always wins. If the underlying database value of the focused control was changed by another user while the input is fouced, that change gets overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a helper that will track the IsKeyboardFocusWithin property and update the target value only if it does not contain keyboard focus.
In example, you have specific source that changes every second:

```
    public partial class MainWindow {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Data", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnDataChanged));

    static void OnDataChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        Debug.WriteLine((string)e.NewValue);
    }

    public string Data {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        dt.Tick += Dt_Tick;
        dt.Start();
    }

    void Dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Data = new Random().Next(0, 100).ToString();
    }
}
```

In this case this is the Data property. Now, helper. I decided to create it as a MarkupExtension to simplify XAML:

```
 public class SynchronizationHelperExtension : MarkupExtension {
    public Binding Binding { get; set; }
    class Helper {            
        static int index = 0;
        bool locked = false;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HelperProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Helper", typeof(Helper), typeof(Helper), new PropertyMetadata(default(Helper)));

        public static void SetHelper(DependencyObject element, Helper value) {
            element.SetValue(HelperProperty, value);
        }

        public static Helper GetHelper(DependencyObject element) {
            return (Helper)element.GetValue(HelperProperty);
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FocusProperty", typeof(bool), typeof(Helper), new PropertyMetadata(false, (o, args) => GetHelper(o)?.OnFocusPropertyChanged(o, (bool)args.OldValue, (bool)args.NewValue)));            
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SourceProperty", typeof(object), typeof(Helper), new PropertyMetadata(false, (o, args) => GetHelper(o)?.OnSourcePropertyChanged(o, args.OldValue, args.NewValue)));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TargetProperty", typeof(object), typeof(Helper), new PropertyMetadata(false, (o, args) => GetHelper(o)?.OnTargetPropertyChanged(o, args.OldValue, args.NewValue)));

        void OnTargetPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, object oldValue, object newValue) {
            o.SetValue(SourceProperty, newValue);
        }
        void OnSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, object oldValue, object newValue) {
            if (locked)
                return;
            o.SetValue(TargetProperty, newValue);
        }
        void OnFocusPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, bool oldValue, bool newValue) {
            locked = newValue;
        }
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        var helper = new Helper();
        var ipwt = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
        var dObj = ipwt.TargetObject as DependencyObject;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(dObj, Helper.FocusProperty, new Binding() {Path = new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithinProperty), RelativeSource = RelativeSource.Self});
        Binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(dObj, Helper.SourceProperty, Binding);
        Helper.SetHelper(dObj, helper);
        return new Binding() {Path = new PropertyPath(Helper.TargetProperty), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus, RelativeSource = RelativeSource.Self }.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}
```

We have 3 properties: 
one stores actual value from source (`Helper.SourceProperty`)
second - stores the target value (`Helper.TargetProperty`)
and the third used to lock synchronization between these properties (Helper.FocusProperty)
Also we have the Binding property - this is the binding that you use to bind your Target property with the source (e.g. `TextBox.Text` with the `MainWindow.Data`)
In the ProvideValue method we:

1. binding the `FrameworkElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithinProperty` with the `Helper.FocusProperty` to lock updets
2. updating the original binding to make it TwoWay (to update the `Data` property after change)
3. returning BindingExpression to the `Helper.TargetProperty`

The XAML will look like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{local:SynchronizationHelper Binding={Binding Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{local:SynchronizationHelper Binding={Binding Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=Data}"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

[And the short video demonstrating the result](http://screencast.com/t/gX3vuFZ5p)